# Как показать в uml диаграмме классов наследование от системного класса(c#)

Tags: c#, uml

Как я могу показать на `uml` диаграмме классов наследование от системного класса .

Пример

```
public class Myform : Form
```

Comment: Я, конечно, не знаток, но почему бы просто не положить на диаграмму и системный `Form`?

Comment: Как поместить системный Form на мою диаграмму?

Comment: Вручную, точно так же, как вы помещаете Myform?

Comment: Только при автоматической генерации кода по uml диаграмме у меня получится, что класс Form будет считаться созданным мной, а не системным, как требуется.

Comment: Ах вот оно что! Ну, тогда это по идее зависит от конкретной программы, которая это делает. Добавьте информацию об этом в вопрос, может, натолкнёт кого-то на идею.

Comment: @ПавелХвойницкий, Есть хороший софт Power Designer, у него хорошая поддержка c#, попробуйте

Comment: спасибо попробую

Comment: Так всё-таки, какой софт вы используете для проектирования UML и кодогенерации? Я знаю, в некоторых тулах есть возможность указать пакеты (сборки, библиотеки) в которых содержатся системные классы.